# Word 2013 regex replace e.g. "<1.5%" with "1.5% Maximum"

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word, word-2013

I have a number of documents that contain texts such as:

```
<0.4%

<1%

<1.5%
```

In each of the above cases, I want to replace the matches with the following strings:

```
0.4% Maximum

1% Maximum

1.5% Maximum
```

**Edit**: As a starting point, I attempted to find the numbers only with `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+` as a *Find What* entry (found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)). This only found numbers like `0.04` and not `0.4` or `1.5` as examples.

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far, it's easy even if you're not an IT specialist as long as you have understood regex and capture groups.

Comment: @stribizhev "Contains a Pattern Match Expression which is not valid"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that MS Word does not have regular expression support. It supports wildcards, though.

MS Word 2013 as its predecessors does not support 0 or more occurrences quantifier. Even if you specify the number of occurrences with `{0,100}` limiting quantifier, an error will be raised.

Also, since there is no alternation operator, you cannot add alternatives to one search expression.

You need to perform several S&R operations:

1. Search: `[<]([0-9]@.[0-9]@)%`, Replace: `\1% Maximum`.
2. Search: `[<]([0-9]@)%`, Replace: `\1% Maximum`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the result of following regex :

```
'[^\d]*([0-9.]+%)'
```

with a back-reference number and the word `Maximum`:

```
'\1 Maximum' #or in some regex engines use `$1` for match the group
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this gives the error: ^ is not a valid special character....